# How do I populate a MySQL table with many random numbers?

Tags: mysql

I'm going to ask a question that has been asked in [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505930/populate-mysql-table-with-random-data-in-python) abstract [terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844527/how-to-populate-a-database-column-with-random-numbers), with (understandably) no concrete answers provided:

From the MySQL prompt, how do I create and populate a table, `rand_numbers`, with one column, `number INT`, and 1111 rows, where the `number` column holds a random number between 2222 and 5555?

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE rand_numbers(number INT);

 #run following line 1111 times
INSERT INTO rand_numbers (number) VALUES (2222 + CEIL( RAND() * 3333));
```

This question has been asked, but either [relies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551755/postgresql-how-to-efficient-populate-table-with-10-millions-rows-with-random-st) on [external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927933/how-to-insert-random-numbers-mysql) languages for the loop or is [far too general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371503/sql-populate-table-with-random-data).  I would like to know if it's possible to do something this simple from a typical Linux MySQL prompt.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop-statement.html

Comment: The second link you have (the "external" one) is using an SQL procedure. You can define and run it from the prompt just fine.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To create the table use:

```
CREATE TABLE rand_numbers (
    number INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Then to populate it with random values, you can define a [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) (which supports looping):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRand(IN NumRows INT, IN MinVal INT, IN MaxVal INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            INSERT INTO rand_numbers VALUES (MinVal + CEIL(RAND() * (MaxVal - MinVal)));
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertRand(1111, 2222, 5555);
```

Then you can reuse that procedure to insert more random values based on different parameters.. say 600 rows with random values between 1200 and 8500:

```
CALL InsertRand(600, 1200, 8500);
```

Comment: So basically it is not possible to populate a column with random numbers in one query? W/o `PROCEDURE` or other hacking

Answer (score 39):

Without creating a stored procedure, one technique I've applied is to use the table itself to add the columns.  First seed it with a value...

```
INSERT INTO rand_numbers ( number ) VALUES ( rand() * 3333 );
```

Then insert again, selecting from this table to double the rows each time...

```
INSERT INTO rand_numbers ( number ) SELECT number * rand() FROM rand_numbers;
```

You don't need to run the second query that many times to get quite a few random rows. Not as "neat" as using a stored procedure of course, just proposing an alternative.

As pointed out by [mohamed23gharbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3382822/mohamed23gharbi), you can run into duplicates if your test mass is too large. You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip duplicates if that is a problem.

Comment: this was surprisingly useful - and quick - took less than a minute on the cli to add 2 million records. exponential ftw

Comment: very useful and clever tip:
based on exponential evolution of the number of rows, but some times you fell on a duplicate when you reach larger number of inserts

Comment: @Mohamed23gharbi better use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip duplicates.

Comment: You should change your code from `SELECT number * rand()` to `SELECT var_int * rand()` - Otherwise you constantly reduce the pool of numbers the random int is generated from. Set `var_int` to the maximum value of your desired random int.

Comment: The standard & some DBMSs don't specify that a function is called more than once in a query, so this only works if a DBMS says it does. MySQL doesn't say it does.

Answer (score 20):

The task can be done also this way:

```
-- scale from 0 to MAX

UPDATE `table` SET `column` = 1000 * RAND() WHERE 1;

-- scale from MIN to MAX

UPDATE `table` SET `column` = MIN + (MAX - MIN) * RAND() WHERE 1;
```

You can also use math function like FLOOR(), CEIL(), etc. in the expression..

Comment: What does `WHERE 1` mean?

Comment: This really works. This is much simpler and better than accepted answer with long `procedure` thing.

Comment: @Green The update affects all the rows that achieve the condition in `WHERE` then as `WHERE 1` means true all the rows will be affected.

Comment: The standard & some DBMSs don't specify that a function is called more than once in a query, so this only works if a DBMS says it does. MySQL doesn't say it does.

Comment: Still works after all these years! :-) Yes, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have always used this -

```
insert into rand_numbers ( number ) select rand() from (
    select 0 as i
    union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
    union select 4 union select 5 union select 6
    union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) as t1, (
    select 0 as i
    union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
    union select 4 union select 5 union select 6
    union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) as t2, (
    select 0 as i
    union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
    union select 4 union select 5 union select 6
    union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) as t3;
```

Inserts 1000 random numbers. On-the-fly tables `t1`, `t2`, `t3` are cross joined so we get 10x10x10 rows.

So, for like a million rows, just add 3 more of
`(select 0 as i union select 1 ...) as` statements. This seems convenient to me, since there's not much effort copy-pasting a few lines a bunch of times.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 3):

If you are lazy and you have the query for creating the table, try http://filldb.info//