# Can't use current iterator value in MySQL's INSERT query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm playing with MySQL stored procedure from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11042619/1469208) to insert many rows with random data.

When I'm executing query that inserts rows containing value only from my own variable:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertRand;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRand(IN NumRows INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            SET @devname = CONV(FLOOR(RAND() * 99999999999999), 20, 36);
            INSERT INTO `devices` VALUES (NULL, FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 3)), NULL, CONCAT('Device ', @devname), CONCAT('Description for device ', @devname, '.'), ROUND(RAND()));
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertRand(77);
```

then everything is fine. But, when I'm trying to extend inserted data with current iterator value:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertRand;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRand(IN NumRows INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            SET @devname = CONV(FLOOR(RAND() * 99999999999999), 20, 36);
            INSERT INTO `devices` VALUES (NULL, FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 3)), NULL, CONCAT('Device no ', @i), CONCAT('Description for device no ', @i, ' and device ID = ', @devname, '.'), ROUND(RAND()));
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertRand(77);
```

then I'm getting `#1048 - Column 'name' cannot be null`.

Column `name` is third in my `INSERT` query. When I'm pushing `CONCAT('Device ', @devname)` into it, all is fine. Changing this to `CONCAT('Device no ', @i)` fails ugly.

This must be something awfully obvious, but I'm struggling with this for past two hours (MySQL newbie I am) and I don't see the light in the tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) (`@i`) and local variables [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) (`i`), are different variables.

```sql
// `@i` is NULL
... CONCAT('Device no ', @i) ... // CONCAT('Device no ', NULL) = NULL
```

Comment: Ahh... bloody obvious! :|