# How to generate random 10 digit number and place into database table?

Tags: mysql, database

I am working with a MySQL database that has a table of customers. One of the columns consist of `phone_numbers` `varchar(10)`. My question is how can I create a simple loop that goes through all the customers and inserts a random phone numbers?

[customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS2vL.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I populate a MySQL table with many random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042546/how-do-i-populate-a-mysql-table-with-many-random-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` statement with the `RAND` and `LPAD` functions (docs: [RAND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)).

Example (generates numbers from 0000000000 to 9999999999): `UPDATE table SET phone_numbers = LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 10000000000), 10, '0')`